# Spring MVC + Thymeleaf: Can not send a value via GET method

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I create a form in order to search by date using Spring MVC and Thymeleaf. This is the form:

```
<form role="form" action="#" th:action="@{buscar(fecha=${fecha})}" method="get" id="frmBuscar">
    <div class="form-group form-inline col-xs-5">
        <label>Mes</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm monthPiker" name="fecha" id="fecha"/>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="buscarRetencion" value="Buscar Retenciones"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I noticed that action value is `"buscar?fecha="` instead of `"buscar?fecha=5-5-2015"`. I need to capture the value of the field `"fecha"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove fecha parameter from the form action (use `th:action="@{buscar}"` instead of `th:action="@{buscar(fecha=${fecha})}"`).

There's a form field `fecha` and the duplicity probably causes the problem.